# pmdarima package auto_arima() returned model with empty square bracket?

Tags: forecasting

I am using auto_arima() function in pmdarima package.
In its summary() results it returned a best model specification as:

Model:  SARIMAX(2, 1, 2)x(2, 0, [], 7)

But I can't find any explanation in the pmdarima documentation what it would mean if they return a model specification with an empty square bracket.

Could anyone help me what the empty square bracket [] represents in the model specification?

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a Minimal (!) Working (!) Example. Thank you!

Comment: I am just asking how should I interpret the "square brackets" in the model specification from auto_arima() results. I am not asking why square brackets are shown.